# Chrome Extension with CRA - web accessible resources

Tags: google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

I am building a chrome extension with create-react-app.

This gives me a folder structure as follows:

```
my_app/
    public/
        options.html
        popup.html
        manifest.json
src/
    background.js
    index.js
    options.js
```

I want to add a new html page to the extension which can then be called via `chrome-extension://[runtime_id]/my_new_page.html`

To do so, I placed `my_new_page.html` in the `/public` folder and added it to `manifest.json` under `web_accessible_resources`.

However when I load `chrome-extension://[runtime_id]/my_new_page.html` I get only the boilerplate of my_new_page.html and the js which is supposed to render the app content, is not run.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the way my `webpack.config` handled my bundles. Whatever goes into the build folder is handled by webpack and thus configurations might be required - and can vary depending on what boilerplate/template you are using.